# Different MD5 hashes for .net and java

Tags: java, vb.net, encryption

`I want to encode my string using .net and pass it to a java program. I am using the same program for encryption and decryption on both the sides. But the java program and .net programs are returning different MD5 hash codes.

Here are the codes for both my programs :

VB.net

```
md5Provider = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
input = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sSecurityKey)
oHash = oMd5CryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash(input)
```

Java

```
MessageDigest m;
m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] UTF8bytes = key.getBytes("UTF8");
m.update(UTF8bytes,0,UTF8bytes.length);
```

Edit: The hash computed using vb.net is 
{170,226,106,33,183,52,99,154,17,225,135,139,170,141,116,108}

The m.digest() i get in java is 
{-44, 29, -116, -39, -113, 0, -78, 4, -23, -128, 9, -104, -20, -8, 66, 126}

The problem is that m.digest() from java and oHash from vb.net are different. So i cant go further with DES encryption.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you could paste the hashes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found the answer. I just converted the Md5 hash into BigInteger and then converted into an byte array. Now when i pass it as a key to the DES algorithm, i get my desired output.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to compare input from both digest methods byte by byte. That is `input` from VB.net and `UTF8bytes` from Java. Most likely they will be different (could be some encoding specifics of VB.net, for example). Also, how do you compare results?

Comment: i have added hashes from both the programs

Comment: More interesting is to make sure that input is exactly the same. It could be just one extra byte, like 0 or end of line and hash would be totally different.

Comment: Also since Java does not have unsigned byte you may want to convert it correctly. Because VB clearly shows unsigned bytes.

Comment: @AlexGitelman: The signed versus unsigned is not an issue. You don't have to convert the Java bytes to something else. Your first comment is almost certainly the cause for the problem.